# Qt, QTouchEvents not send to QGraphicsItem

Tags: qt, multi-touch

I manually create `QTouchEvents` and send them to a `QGraphicsView's viewport()`. While the `QGraphicsScene` does get the events, my `QGraphicsItem`s (or ...Objects) don't. `setAcceptTouchEvents` is set to true:

```
myObject::myObject(QGraphicsItem * parent)
    : QGraphicsItem(parent)
{
    setAcceptTouchEvents(true);
}

...

bool myObject::sceneEvent( QEvent * event )
{
    switch (event->type()) {
      case QEvent::TouchBegin:
      case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
      case QEvent::TouchEnd:
        //this is never reached?!
        return true;
    }

    return QGraphicsItem::sceneEvent(even);
}

//in a different class:
  QTouchEvent * event = new QTouchEvent(t,QTouchEvent::TouchScreen,Qt::NoModifier,states,tpList);
  if(m_view->viewport())
  {
      qApp->postEvent(m_view->viewport(), event);
  }
```

Also, I get `"QGestureManager::deliverEvent: could not find the target for gesture"` warnings, though I don't even try to grab `QGesture`s anywhere in my program.